# Rails include only selected columns from relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I will try to explain:

I have a table 'Product' and a table 'Store'. I'm trying to get just the store name to show at the page, but ActiveRecord is returning me all the columns from the store.

Here is the code:

```
@product = Product
          .order(id: :desc)
          .includes(:store)
          .select("products.id, products.store_id, stores.name")
          .limit(1)
```

The built query (from Rails):

```
Processing by IndexController#index as HTML
Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  products.id, products.store_id FROM `products`  ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
Store Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `stores`.* FROM `stores` WHERE `stores`.`id` IN (111)
```

I just want to show the product's store name, but Rails is selecting all the store columns.

My models:

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store, :foreign_key => 'store_id'
end
```

Store.rb:

```
class Loja < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this via pluck and joins:

```
Product
  .order(id: :desc)
  .joins(:store)
  .pluck("products.id, products.store_id, stores.name")
  .limit(1)
```

You're going to get an array back that follows the order of the columns defined in pluck. [I've written about pluck before if you're not familiar with it.](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/getting-to-know-pluck-and-select/)

---

The other way is via a straight SQL query:

```
sql =<<-EOF
  SELECT products.id, products.store_id, stores.name
  FROM products INNER JOIN stores
    ON products.store_id = stores.id
  ORDER BY products.id DESC
  LIMIT 1
EOF
records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

#=> [{"id" => X, "store_id" => Y, "name" => Z, ... }]
```

Both options produce the same SQL statement, the just vary in how the results come out.

Comment: The SQL you gave can be written straight using AR.

Comment: But with pluck it won't be an object anymore, correct?

Comment: @HerlonAguiar that's right, it's going to return an array of values. That's one of the drawbacks of pluck vs select.

Comment: @GavinMiller, there is a way to access the result by something like this: product["store"]["name"] ?

Comment: @HerlonAguiar not that I'm aware of. The straight sql may be a better approach for you if you're looking to "key" your values back.

Answer (score 6):

Just tried something similar to this on my project. This should work:

```
@products = Product.
  .order(id: :desc)
  .joins(:store)
  .select("products.id, products.store_id, stores.name")
  .limit(1)
```

Using `joins` as opposed to `includes` will make rails perform only one query, because `joins` doesn't eager-load the association.

Comment: Thanks for the answer But I already tried,it also are loading All the store columns

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have something on Product (perhaps a default scope or an after_initialize) that loads the stores?