# Ruby - how to fetch additional data from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's a `.map` block - pretty standard I'd say:

```
@grouped_data = data_source.group_by(&:manufacturer_id).map do |k,v| 
                           { 
                             ...,
                             manufacturer_id: k, 
                             manufacturer_name: Manufacturer.find(k).name,
                             manufacturer_email: Manufacturer.find(k).email,
                             manufacturer_founded: Manufacturer.find(k).founded,
                             ...
                           }      
                         end
```

It's not very effective to call the manufacturer model all the time I need to grab an attribute from there... what's the best practice in such cases?

Ideal would be something like

```
@grouped_data = data_source.group_by(&:manufacturer_id).map do |k,v| 
                               { 
                                 manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(manufacturer_id)

                                 ...,
                                 manufacturer_id: k, 
                                 manufacturer_name: manufacturer.name,
                                 manufacturer_email: manufacturer.email,
                                 manufacturer_founded: manufacturer.founded,
                                 ...
                               }      
                             end
```

But this is not acceptable way... how to figure this out?

Comment: _"But this is not acceptable way"_ Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `includes` is for when fetching, you can pre-join in additional data, like `includes(:manufacturer)` if that relationship exists.

As a bonus that should link it all up for you, and you can still do your Ruby `group_by` if you want.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. In the query, I use `.joins(:manufacturer)`. As the `Manufacturer` model is quite large (~70 fields), I didn't want to include it always, as I thought it might be quite slowing. So I thought it might be, performance-wise, a better option to "somehow" fetch it later... Out of those 70 fields, I need like 5.

Comment: You can do a selective inclusion if you prefer, using [`select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select).

Comment: you can check this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925752/4414956